# Running a jasmine test with TypeScript fails using Resharper test runner

Tags: typescript, jasmine, resharper

I've started to mix **TypeScript** and **Jasmine** to test my project. I'm running test using **Resharper 10** on **Visual Studio 2015**. This is my sample test:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

var HomeViewModel = require("../app/viewmodels/home.ts");

describe("Something", ()=> {

    it("This test is ok.", () => {
        expect(23).toBe(23);
    });

    it("Home View Model", () => {
      var vm = new HomeViewModel();
      expect(vm.title).toBe("Home");
    });
});
```

But when I run the test using **Resharper** it says:

```
Inconclusive: Test not run.
```

But if I remove the second test and the `import` line it will pass.

What is wrong with my test?

Comment: This is the same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747521/typescript-collections-jasmine-visual-studio-2015/39106605#39106605